# I cant figure out OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

Okay, so I'm just trying to figure out how to setup the Google API so I can get to working on my APP, but I'm either missing the obvious or I just don't quite get it.

So, when I see OAuth2 its usually followed by the Drive SDK and whenever I try to go set that up it seems like I need to have a website too so that it will work. Am I right there or am I not getting it?

And what exactly is a valid 'Open URL'? I can't find anything that properly explains this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a webserver, but it doesn't need to be a publicly accessible web site. If you have a local Apache server running n your development box, that will work fine. You just need to give  it a domain name in your /etc/hosts file (eg. localhost.example.com), and then specify that as the Open URL.